# Outlook 2007 + Asp.net C# get email properties from Outlook to a custom C# form

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, outlook-2007

My requirement when user selects a particular mail and clicks the menu item it will display the particular mail details (To, cc, bcc, subject, Body, attachments…) in custom form.

Comment: Where does ASP.NET fits in? Is your menu from a web application?

Answer (score 0):

In this case the asp.net application will need to access the MAPI interface to talk to the exchange server to get this information.